# How to print some features and their feature types (categories) as well?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have some features of a vehicle that I want to print in the show of a vehicle. The problem is that the features has categories (or types), and I want to print them as well. But first, let me explain my project:

I have 3 models:

- Vehicles: Vehicles has and belongs to many Features.
- Feature_types: Feature_types has many Features.
- Features: Features belongs to Feature_types and has many and belongs to Vehicles.

So, when I am creating/editing a vehicle I got this (see next pic) to select the features of that vehicle. When I submit the vehicle, these features goes to an array that saves the feature_ids.

```
#vehicle form page
<% FeatureType.all.order("description").each do |ft| %>

  <span><%= ft.description %></span>

  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :feature_ids, ft.features, :id, :description do |b|%>
     <%= b.label{ b.check_box + b.text } %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

[image]

In my vehicle show page, I want to show the feature type followed by the features selected. If one feature_type doesn't have any feature selected then the feature_Type will not show up. But I don't really now how to do this. I can only print all selected featured selected:

```
#vehicle show page
<% @vehicle.features.each do |feature| %>
   <span><i class="fa fa-check"></i><%= feature.description %></span>
<% end %>
```

The output:

[image]

The desired output:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Sorry about the long post. Thank you!

P.S: If you could provide a title for this post I would be grateful! I really don't know how to title this one xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing you are trying to do is [**`group_by`**](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
<% @vehicle.features.group_by(&:feature_type).each do |feature_type, features| %>
  <%= feature_type %>
  <% features.each do |feature| %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You are the best! Thank you so much! ;)